# How to detect (with server-side code) whether an ASP.NET Page is about to be cached (the first time it is requested)?

Tags: asp.net, outputcache

Is it possible to detect whether an ASP.NET Page is about to be cached and if so, how?

The HttpCachePolicy object provides only set-methods. The VaryByParams name-value collection is useless if values other than "None" and "*" are set as it impossible to enumerate them and you can only access them by key.

Additionally, I cannot use Reflection.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

One approach which might work if you're using ASP.NET 4.0 would be to implement your own custom [OutputCacheProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.outputcacheprovider.aspx). You could then add your detection logic inside the provider.

See the [MSDN ASP.NET Caching Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178597.aspx) for examples of adding the provider to your web.config and using the providerName attribute in your @Page or @Control directive.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately I need a 2.0+ solution. My current research shows no way of doing this - ASP.NET effectively shuts every door to the 'private' Cache (where it actually caches things) and one cannot even read a single property giving away any information about the Cache or whether the Page is about to get cached or not.